# C++ Pointer to Pointer to Function Parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters

the following C++ code does not work as I wish.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int Pointer_Function(char* _output);
int Pointer_to_Pointer_Function(char** text );

int main() {

    char* input = "This";
    printf("1. %s \n", input);
    Pointer_Function(input);
    printf("5. %s \n", input);

       int test;
       std::cin >> test;
}

int Pointer_Function(char* _output) {
       _output = "Datenmanipulation 1";
       printf("2. %s \n", _output);

       Pointer_to_Pointer_Function(&_output);

       printf("4. %s \n", _output);
    return 0;
}

int Pointer_to_Pointer_Function(char** text ) {

       printf("3. %s \n", *text);
       char* input = "HalliHallo";

       text = &input;
       printf("3.1. %s \n", *text);
    return 0;
}
```

I wish as result for printf 5. **HalliHallo** instead of Datenmanipulation. Because data **text** must be changed due to **&input**.

Output:

```
1.This
2. Datenmanipulation 1
3. Datenmanipulation 1
3.1 HalliHallo
4. Datenmanipulation 1
5. This
```

**Expected Result:**

```
1.This
2. Datenmanipulation 1
3. Datenmanipulation 1
3.1 HalliHallo
4. HalliHallo
5. HalliHallo
```

How can I give pointer to pointer to a Function as a Parameter?
Why does not work my Code?

Answer (score 8):

When you assign:

```
text = &input;
```

you're just changing the local variable `text`, you're not changing the contents of the pointer that it pointed to. You should do:

```
*text = input;
```

This will make it print:

```
4. HalliHallo
```

You can't make it print

```
5. HalliHallo
```

because `Pointer_Function` just takes a pointer to the string, not a pointer to the variable, so it can't change the caller's variable.

You should also change all your declarations to specify `const char*` and `const char**`, since you're assigning pointers to literal strings. Here's the fully working code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int Pointer_Function(const char* _output);
int Pointer_to_Pointer_Function(const char** text );

int main() {

    const char* input = "This";
    printf("1. %s \n", input);
    Pointer_Function(input);
    printf("5. %s \n", input);

       int test;
       std::cin >> test;
}

int Pointer_Function(const char* _output) {
       _output = "Datenmanipulation 1";
       printf("2. %s \n", _output);

       Pointer_to_Pointer_Function(&_output);

       printf("4. %s \n", _output);
    return 0;
}

int Pointer_to_Pointer_Function(const char** text ) {

       printf("3. %s \n", *text);
       const char* input = "HalliHallo";

       *text = input;
       printf("3.1. %s \n", *text);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1. This 
2. Datenmanipulation 1 
3. Datenmanipulation 1 
3.1. HalliHallo 
4. HalliHallo 
5. This
```

Comment: I just tried to run your code and it doesnt work with that change

Comment: Your output gives number 5 as This....the OP wants it to say HalliHallo, sorry if I am missing something

Comment: I explained why that isn't possible with a Pointer function, it needs to be Pointer to Pointer.

Comment: ah my bad, I was too busy testing to read the explanation :) Thanks @Barmar

Comment: Maybe it gets easier to understand if you give a short explaination to call-by-value and why pointer-to-pointer is necessary

Comment: There's no such thing as a short explanation of this. I'd have to create ASCII art showing all the boxes and addresses....

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the last function by altering the value of the pointer the pointer
char** is pointing to:

**C**

```
int Pointer_to_Pointer_Function(char** text ) {
    *text = "HalliHallo";
    return 0;
}
```

To fix both function you might pass by reference:

**C++**

```
int Reference_to_Pointer_Function(char*& text ) {
    text =  "HalliHallo";
    return 0;
}
```

In C++11 a string literal has the (decayed) type 'char const*' (the conversion
to char* is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in you Pointer_to_pointer_function

```
int Pointer_to_Pointer_Function(char** text ) {

       printf("3. %s \n", *text);
       char* input = "HalliHallo";

       text = &input;
       printf("3.1. %s \n", *text);
    return 0;
}
```

You pass a **pointer to pointer to char** as argument to the function.
The variable **input is pointer to char**. Because of that `text = &input;`is not correct. You are assigning the address of a pointer to a pointer to pointer to char. The assignment should be `*text = &input;`

You probably notice there is no need to use pointer to pointer here; not for what you are doing. You would need it if you were passing an in/out parameter to the function.